# Protractor: Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document for points in map

Tags: protractor, webdriver

I use the following function in the protractor test. Test run causes `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` is thrown. The test is being executed for various page versions.

```
openPointDescription: function(){
    widget.points.each(function(point){
            widget.pointDescription.container.isPresent().then(function(present){
                if (!present)
                {
                    browser.actions().mouseMove(point).click().perform().then();
                }
            })
    });   
}
```

Where:

```
 widget.points: element.all(by.tagWithAttributeRegex('img', 'src', '.*marker.png')),
 pointDescritption.container: element(by.css('div[class=bp-point-desc]')),
```

Stacktrace indicates mouseMove function

```
[chrome #01-13]   - Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
[chrome #01-13]   (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.85)
[chrome #01-13]   (Driver info: chromedriver=90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}),platform=Linux 4.4.0-187-generic x86_64)
[chrome #01-13]     (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.85)
[chrome #01-13]     (Driver info: chromedriver=90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}),platform=Linux 4.4.0-187-generic x86_64)
[chrome #01-13]       at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
[chrome #01-13]       at parseHttpResponse (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
[chrome #01-13]       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[chrome #01-13]   From: Task: mouseMove
[chrome #01-13]       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js:124:23
[chrome #01-13]       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js:123:29
[chrome #01-13]       at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
[chrome #01-13]       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
[chrome #01-13]       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[chrome #01-13]   From: Task: ActionSequence.perform
[chrome #01-13]       at ActionSequence.perform (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js:122:33)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/src/widget/widget.pageController.js:31:68
[chrome #01-13]       at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
[chrome #01-13]       at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
[chrome #01-13]       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27
[chrome #01-13]       at /var/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
[chrome #01-13]       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
[chrome #01-13]   From: Task: Run it("displays point description after clicking on a valid point") in control flow
[chrome #01-13]       at UserContext.<anonymous> (/var/app/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
[chrome #01-13]   From asynchronous test: 
[chrome #01-13]   Error
[chrome #01-13]       at Suite.<anonymous> (/var/app/src/widget/spec/genericSpec.js:21:13)
[chrome #01-13]       at Object.generateDescribe (/var/app/src/widget/spec/genericSpec.js:8:9)
[chrome #01-13]       at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/src/widget/spec/widget5.9.spec.js:5:13)
[chrome #01-13]       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
[chrome #01-13]       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
[chrome #01-13]       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
[chrome #01-13]
```

Answer (score 1):

90% chance the problem is `.each`. Try with `for` loop instead. But I never worked with `.then` syntax, so using `async/await`

```
async openPointDescription: function() {
  for(let i=0; i<await widget.points.count(); i++) {
    if (!(await widget.pointDescription.container.isPresent())) { // it looks like this has to go outside of for loop
      await browser.actions().mouseMove(widget.points.get(i)).perform()
      await widget.points.get(i).click()
    }
  }
```